# How to create a bottom navigation view where one view item is always highlighted irrespective it is selected or not

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottom-nav-view

[image]

The middle view item is what I need to develop for my app I have tried using a layout with image and textview for item but still doesn't work